# How is it that you can do `Integer('1')` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How does the standard library allow you to coerce a `String` into an `Integer` with `Integer('1') #=> 1`? Is there a language feature that allows one to create this kind of conversion syntax in a class?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. It's a method on the `Kernel` class named `Integer`; the fact that it's named the same as a class is for convenience. It converts its argument to an integer.

Comment: Are you asking for the implementation details ?
Not sure what you're aiming at with your question.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I guess that the OP is asking because it is has been designed to look like some magic on the `Integer` class. It isn't always clear  what is going on, especially as using the upper-cased name goes against the usually taught Ruby standards.

Comment: @NeilSlater Yeah, I see that now. It was just not clear what OP was asking.

Comment: Personally, I think it's pretty clear what's going on. Since it takes an argument, it *must* be a method, anything else just doesn't make sense. Methods are the only thing in Ruby that can take arguments. Variables can't take arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [not a class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer), just a method in disguise.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this -

```
 '1'.to_i => 1
```

Comment: This is the convention used in most code. Many objects define `to_i` and `to_s` convenience methods.